# Parsing a string separated by semicolon

Tags: php, mysql, string, parsing

How can I parse this string

```
name:john;phone:12345;website:www.23.com;
```

into becoming like this

```
$name = "john";
$phone = "12345"
.....
```

because I want to save the parameter in one table column, I see joomla using this method to save the menu/article parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this(explode() is the way):

```
$string = 'name:john;phone:12345;website:www.23.com';

$array = explode(';',$string);

foreach($array as $a){
  if(!empty($a)){
   $variables = explode(':',$a);
   $$variables[0] = $variables[1];
  }
}

echo $name;
```

[Working example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c707b4316dda7f2212a30213b397ecee179df054)

Please note: String must be like this, `variable_name:value;variable_name2:value` and the `variable_name` or `variable` cant contain `;` or `:`

Comment: How do you actually define ugliness of code? When its not easy to understand?

Comment: thank you JTC, i just try to use longer parameter (i add one more something:par;) but it error
is it work only for 3 parameter ?

Comment: Show the longer parameter, but understand the string must be like this, `variable_name:value;variable_name2:value` and the variable_name or variable cant contain `;` or `:` and on the end of the string should not be `;`

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/9a674246e449f3beb8629fa0a51070b9fa0335ff i got error when i add longer parameter

Comment: @user2801717 I just updated my answer and my working example check it out this shoould work for you

Comment: yeah, its working!!
thank you very much JTC 
you save my weekend :D

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I'd do it:

- Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) and split the string with `;` as the delimiter.
- Loop through the result array and [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) by `:`
- Store the second part in a variable and push it into the result array
- Optionally, if you want to convert the result array back into a string, you can use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode)

Code:

```
$str = 'name:john;phone:12345;website:www.23.com;';
$parts = explode(';', $str);
foreach ($parts as $part) {
    if(isset($part) && $part != '') {
        list($item, $value) = explode(':', $part);
        $result[] = $value;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => john
    [1] => 12345
    [2] => www.23.com
)
```

Now, to get these values into variables, you can simply do:

```
$name = $result[0];
$phone = $result[1];
$website = $result[2];
```

### [Demo!](http://codepad.org/m8VmJRGt)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but this doesn't end up with exactly the result that was asked for

Comment: @JAL: That part was self-explanatory, but I've added it in my answer, now. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [explode()](http://php.net/explode)

explode — ***Split a string by string***

**Description**

Returns an array of strings, each of which is a substring of string formed by splitting it on boundaries formed by the string delimiter.

```
  <?php

    $string = "name:john;phone:12345;website:www.23.com;";

    $pieces = explode(";", $string);

    var_dump($pieces);

?>
```

**Output**

```
array(4) {
  [0]=>
  string(9) "name:john"
  [1]=>
  string(11) "phone:12345"
  [2]=>
  string(18) "website:www.23.com"
  [3]=>
  string(0) ""
}
```

[DEMO](http://codepad.org/xzQNS3lK)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<?php

$str = "name:john;phone:12345;website:www.23.com";

$array=explode(";",$str);

if(count($array)!=0)
{
foreach($array as $value)
{

    $data=explode(":",$value);

    echo $data[0]." = ".$data[1];
    echo "<br>";
}
}
?>
```

Comment: $array evaluates to false in a Boolean context if the array is empty, so if($array) is a tiny bit more concise